# Reverse the bounds of a summation

Tags: summation

I'm trying to figure out how reversing the sum works. I know it involves changing or switching variables, but I'm stuck on how to do that.

How do I go from $c + \sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-2} d(n - i)$ to $c + \sum\limits_{i=2}^{n} d(i)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=0}^{n-2}d(n-i)&=d(n)+d(n-1)+\dots+d(n-(n-2))\\
&=d(n)+d(n-1)+\dots+d(2)\\
&=d(2)+d(3)+\dots+d(n)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=2}^{n} d(i)
\end{align}
$$
Then add both sides by $c$.

Comment: I understand how you arrived at $d(i)$ but I still don't get how the bounds are changed.

Comment: The issue is to write the finite sum. Look, the first term is $d(2)$ and the last term is $d(n)$, right? So, with respect to $d(i)$, naturally the sum starts at $i=2$ and ends with $i=n$.

Comment: Okay, now I get it, thank you!

Comment: Good. You see the check mark at the left side of my answer?You can click it indicating that you accepted my answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, kuya.